# Update aws rekognition ModerationLabel to model version 7.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

im using [AWS PowerShell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWSPowerShell/4.1.512) cmdlet [Find-REKModerationLabel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Find-REKModerationLabel.html) to get image Moderation labels. They recently upgraded to model version 7.0 and will automatically switch to that model in mid March. Does anyone know whether its currently possible to use model 7 from within powershell?